# NullPointerException in @InjectMock

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl  {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

public void createUser(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}

public User getUser(long userId) {
    return userRepository.findById(userId).get();
}

public void updateUser(long userId, User user) {
    User userRaw = userRepository.findById(userId).get();
    userRaw.setUserEmail(user.getUserEmail());
    userRaw.setUserName(user.getUserName());
    userRepository.save(userRaw);
}

public List<User> getAllUser() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
}

public void deleteUser(long userId) {
    userRepository.deleteById(userId);
}
```

### }

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UserServiceImplTest {

@InjectMocks
UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;

@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

private final long USERID = 1l;

@Test
public void getUserTest() {
    userServiceImpl.getUser(USERID);
    verify(userRepository).findById(USERID);
    }
}
```

---

I am trying to implement junit and mockito.I am getting null pointer exception in injectMock object.

Comment: can you please post the full error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

While using @Mock, @InjectMocks, test cases need to be run using **MockitoJUnitRunner**.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Alternatively, you can run your test class by enabling MockitoJUnit runner programmatically.

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Secondly, when you use your mock object in a test case you have do define your rules.

```
when(userServiceImpl.getUser(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(0);
```

Comment: `While using @Mock, @InjectMocks, test cases need to be run using MockitoJUnitRunner.` this is NOT TRUE it works with spring runner too

Answer (score 0):

you have to to add `@Autowired` on service injection.

```java
@Autowired
@InjectMocks
UserServiceImpl userServiceImpl;
```